# Using pause in c

Tags: c, operating-system

I wrote a program that given an integer `n` as argument creates `n-1` child processes.The `pid_t` variables used in fork are stored in an array.For each child every `pid[i]=-1` except `pid[childs_number]=0`.So when i write `if(pid[1]==0)` the  code inside the if statement belongs to child one(i checked it by printing `getpid()` inside).

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


void handler(){

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int n=argv[1][0]-'0';
   pid_t pid[n];
   for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
   {
       pid[i]=fork();
       if(pid[i]==0)
       {
           for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
           {
               if(i!=j)
               {
                   pid[j]=-1;
               }
           }
           break;
       }
       wait(0);
   }
   if(pid[1]==0)
   {
       signal(SIGINT,handler);
       pause;
       printf("why");
   }

}
```

So after using pause i expect process with `pid[1]=0` to wait for a SIGINT signal in order to continue running.However, running this code prints the string inside the if statement even though i haven't sent a SIGINT signal. Why is this happening and how could i fix it?

Comment: `pause;` doesn't your compiler issue a warning here?

Comment: In case you meant `system("pause")`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong

Comment: doesn't your favourite C book don't tell you not to use `system("pause");`?

Comment: My guess it's a typo & OP meant to use `pause();` not `pause;` or `system("pause");`

Comment: If instead of `pause;`, you write `int ret = pause();`, what is the value of `ret`?